# In the triangle ABC, D and E are points of trisection of segment AB; F is the midpoint of segment AC. What is the ratio: MN/BF

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image: Triangle ABC]

This is a euclidean geometry problem. No angles measures are given. There are no right angles given. DE/AB = 1/3; AF = FC. I have tried countless extensions and constructions betond what is shown to find something to prove a ratio of MN to anything. I have been stumped.

Comment: Your statement $DE/AB=1/3$ doesn't convey all the information in the problem statement you included. It says that $D$ and $E$ are the points of trisection of $AB$. (Imagine if $DE$ were the same length, but shifted a bit towards $A$.)

Comment: Are you permitted to use coordinates? Vectors?

Comment: if D & E are points of trisection of AB, then isn't DE  1/3 of AB? They are not from trisecting angle C.

Comment: Yes, but if $DE=(1/3)AB$, that doesn't necessarily mean that $D$ and $E$ are points of trisection.

Comment: well, then, I'm more confused because that takes me even further from determining a ratio for MN/BF

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that when you wrote $DE/AB = 1/3$, this was not a correct restatement of the problem, since you were leaving information out. $DE/AB = 1/3$ isn't wrong, it's just incomplete.

Comment: ok. gotchya. but, no, I'm not supposed to use coordinates or vectors. Only extensions, bisectors, etc. etc. to prove a relationship but not by measuring.

Comment: I was not writing DE/AB = 1/3 as an answer to the problem or as a re statement, just part of the info essentially given

Comment: At the moment, I don't see how to do this without coordinates or vectors. However, perhaps you should use coordinates to find the answer and at least see what you're trying to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given data are not enough to determine $\frac{MN}{BF}$. See the picture:
[image]

We need more information, for example the ratio $\frac{BD}{BA}$. If we assume that $D,E$ trisect $AB$, then we can proceed as follows.
[image]

$EF\parallel CD$ implies
$$BM=\frac{BF}{2},EF=\frac{CD}{2},DM=\frac{EF}{2}.$$
From that, we get $EF:CM=2:3$ and
$$\frac{MN}{NF+MN}=\frac{CM}{EF+CM}=\frac{3}{5}$$
That means
$$\frac{MN}{BF}=\frac{MN}{2MF}=\frac3{10}.$$

Comment: The image does say that $D$ and $E$ are the points of trisection of $AB$, so we do know that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is invariant under affine transformations, so choose any coordinates, e.g. like this:

\begin{align*}
A &= (0, 6) & D &= (-4, 2) \\
B &= (-6, 0) & E &= (-2, 4) \\
C &= (0, 0) & M &= (-3, 3/2) \\
F &= (0, 3) & N &= (-6/5, 12/5)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Menelaus Theorem is probably the simplest tool to solve this problem.

First you can apply it in $\Delta ABF$ taking CE as a transversal as:$$\frac{CF}{CA}*\frac{DA}{DB}*\frac{NB}{NF}=1$$

Then you can apply it in $\Delta ABF$ taking CD as a transversal as:$$\frac{CF}{CA}*\frac{EA}{EB}*\frac{MB}{MF}=1$$

Above equations give the values of $\frac{MF}{MB}$ and $\frac{NF}{NB}$ as 4 and 1 which easily give the value of $\frac{MN}{FB}$ as $\frac{3}{10}$

A proof of Menelaus theorem can easily be shown using the Law of Sines.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ABC$ be given with sides $a=11$, $b=8$, and $c=8$. Assume that $D$ and $E$ are on side $BC$ such that $AD$, $AE$ trisect $BAC$. Show that $AD=AE=6$